# Increase items price after successful bid in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an item controller and model as well as a bids controller and model. I want to increase the item's current bid price when a user creates a new bid thats a higher price.

When a user creates an item, they get to set the starting price which is the "price" column in the items table.

My schema is as follows:

```
 create_table "bids", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "amount"
  end

  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "price"
  end
```

Items controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :user_signed_in?

  def index
    @item = Item.all
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])

  end

  def edit
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
    @item.bids.build
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
      redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item successfully created.'
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new'}
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Your item has been updated.'}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit'}
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url }
    end
  end


  private

  def set_item
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def item_params
    params[:item][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params[:item].permit(:price, :user_id, :title, :bids_attributes => [:amount, :user_id, :item_id])
  end



end
```

Bids controller:

```
class BidsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bid, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @bid = Bid.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @bid = @item.bids.build
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @bid = @item.bids.new(bid_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bid.save
        format.html { redirect_to item_url(params[:track_id]), notice: "Bid successfully placed."}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end

    private
    def set_bid
      @bid = Bid.find(params[:id])
    end

    def bid_params
      params[:bid][:user_id] = current_user.id

      params[:bid].permit(:amount, :user_id, :item_id)
    end
end
```

Whats the best way to achieve this? I also need to create a validation that makes sure the entered number is higher then the current price.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this in the controller or the model. I like to do this kind of thing in the model for convenience. One other thing you'll have to worry about is what happens if a bid is removed? You'll need to update the parent as well.

*This code is completely untested*

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base    

  def check_highest_bid
    highest_bid = self.bids.order("amount DESC").first.amount rescue 0
    self.price = highest_bid
    save
  end

end

class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base   

  validate :check_if_highest_bid

  after_save :update_item
  after_destroy :update_item

  def update_item
    self.item.check_highest_bid
  end     

  def check_if_highest_bid
     errors.add(:amount, "must be higher than current bid") unless self.item.price < self.amount
  end
end
```

docs:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Comment: How would I increase the items "price" with the bids "amount" once the bid passes the validation that checks if the amount is higher then the price.

Comment: Thanks. The validation for highest bid works. Just need to figure out how to increase the item's set price.

Comment: What happens if a user gets out bid? They need to get their money back. I created a budget column for users were they can enter their budget. So when ever they place a bid on an item it needs to remove money from their budget, but if they get out bid the money goes back to their account.

Comment: You are asking way more than one question here. ;) I also fixed a bug in `Item#check_highest_bid`. The code is untested but you should be able to figure it out.